# Merging different nodes of multiple XML files using JAVA

Tags: java, xml, merge

I have some xml files in an arrayList, for example `A.xml B.xml`
 and I want to merge some of the nodes while the rest to remain as are using java. I'm new at using so I don't know how to do.

A xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nta>
<declaration>
    bool A, B;
    bool C;
</declaration>
<template>
    <location id="1"  x="10" y="10"/>
    <transition>
        <source ref="3"/>
    </transition>    
</template>
<system> system AND;</system>
</nta>
```

B.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nta>
<declaration>
    int f,k;
    bool D;
</declaration>
<template>
    <location id="100"  x="40" y="89"/>
    <transition>
        <source col="9"/>
    </transition>    
</template>
<system> system OR;</system>
</nta>
```

And the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nta>
<declaration>
    bool A, B;
    bool C;
    int f,k;
    bool D;
</declaration>
<template>
    <location id="1"  x="10" y="10"/>
    <transition>
        <source ref="3"/>
    </transition>    
</template>
<template>
    <location id="100"  x="40" y="89"/>
    <transition>
        <source col="9"/>
    </transition>    
</template>
<system> system AND, OR;</system>
</nta>
```

Basically I want to merge the `declaration` and the `system` and the rest to be serial in the output xml file. How to do this using JAVA? Sorry for the long post!!!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/873604/2071828)

Comment: using `JDOM`it should be piece of cake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In comparison with other available XML processing API, to me,
having `DOMBuilder` and `SAXBuilder` [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) is better for:

- Modifying the XML document
- XML tree traversing and random access to any section
- Merging documents

This is a complete working example for merging two XML document:

```
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    Document doc1 = builder.build(new File("E:\\XML1.xml"));
    Document doc2 = builder.build(new File("E:\\XML2.xml"));

    String rootName = doc1.getRootElement().getName();
    Element newRoot = new Element(rootName);
    Document newDoc = new Document(newRoot);

    Element root1 = doc1.getRootElement();
    Element root2 = doc2.getRootElement();

         // creating declaraion element by merging the declaration content
    Element declaration = new Element("declaration");
    declaration.addContent(root1.getChildText("declaration"));
    declaration.addContent(root2.getChildText("declaration"));
    newRoot.addContent(declaration); // add declaration element to new document

         newRoot.addContent(root1.getChild("template").clone()); 
                       // directly adding template from document XML1, 
                      //after getting template child,
                     //it needs to be cloned to detached  from its parent  

     newRoot.addContent(root2.getChild("template").clone()); 
                       // same for document XML2

     /*** now code yourself  for system element here ***/

    XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter();
    outputter.output(newDoc, System.out); 
                  // output the new doc, pass your OutputStream to this function
```

Comment: Thakn you very much. This works fine. But I have another question. What if there are three different `template` in the first XML and five in the second and I want to keep their structure. How I do this? Using a `for` loop?

Comment: yes. using a `for` loop. give it a try. However, the common style to use the site is to mark an answer accepted if you think it solved your question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't know that. I thougt green arrow goes with vote up and I can't vote until my reputation is 15

Comment: it's ok. you don't have to be sorry. I just wanted to let you know.  Many user avoids new user's question because sometimes they forget to upvote. And thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use an xml parser such as [dom](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp) to read the required parts (declaration and system) and later aggregate them to get your required out put.

you will get plenty of examples on [reading](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) and [writing](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/) xml in java.

Answer (score 0):

Parse XML as i write [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830638/java-parse-xml-and-bind-all-data-content-to-a-map-k-v/19317922#19317922) or  in any another way nad then use javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/)
to do what you want.Create a new XML doc.